# Assertion failure in UITableView Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am getting this error in my rather big iOS project (surely more than 15 different table views in it). So my question is, how can I know which tableView gives me this error? Is it possible? Xcode always shows the bug in AppDelegate.

Full error description:

```
2019-01-29 12:24:24.189428+0100 OrdersApp[28886:8731092] *** Assertion failure in -[UITableView _endCellAnimationsWithContext:], /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/UIKitCore/UIKit-3698.94.10/UITableView.m:2062
2019-01-29 12:24:24.190710+0100 OrdersApp[28886:8731092] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 1.  The number of rows contained in an existing section after the update (1) must be equal to the number of rows contained in that section before the update (2), plus or minus the number of rows inserted or deleted from that section (0 inserted, 0 deleted) and plus or minus the number of rows moved into or out of that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out).'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x234fa0ec4 0x234171a40 0x234eb6b3c 0x2359a51d0 0x2624762c8 0x26248e614 0x26248ea20 0x1023b6c84 0x102399fa0 0x103d9b824 0x103d9cdc8 0x103daaa78 0x234f30df4 0x234f2bcbc 0x234f2b1f0 0x2371a4584 0x262282d40 0x10246a4b0 0x2349eabb4)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)
```

Comment: Post stack trace and full error description

Comment: Add an exception breakpoint: https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/xcode/how-to-create-exception-breakpoints-in-xcode

Comment: @AndréSlotta this worked great. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it explained here:

```
2019-01-29 12:24:24.190710+0100 OrdersApp[28886:8731092] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 1.  The number of rows contained in an existing section after the update (1) must be equal to the number of rows contained in that section before the update (2), plus or minus the number of rows inserted or deleted from that section (0 inserted, 0 deleted) and plus or minus the number of rows moved into or out of that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out).'
```

you probably delete some data from your data source and forgot to delete the corresponding `UITableViewCell` before ending tableView update.

You should do the following in order:

```
tableView.beginUpdates()
dataSource.remove(at: <#index#>)
tableView.deleteRows(at: [<#indexPath#>], with: .automatic)
tableView.endUpdates()
```

All exceptions throwing from `UIKit` could be catch with exception breakpoint.  It will points to the point right before the crash and you can detect it.

[image: Exception break point]

And don't forget to try Simulator. It would be great for catching these kind of exceptions.

Comment: Yes thank you, I know WHY this error occours and it is not what I am asking about. The question was HOW to decide based on debbuger info which TableView is throwing this error.

Comment: So you should add an exception breakpoint. It will points to the point right before the crash and you can detect it. Answer updated @PawełZgoda-Ferchmin

Answer (score 0):

Hmm add for each tableView a tag: 
tableView.tag = 0

Now you can debug this in log "po tableView.tag" or you can write a print("BLA: ", tableView.tag") in your delegate.

Comment: And where would I see that tag later?

Comment: In your log and you can see which one of your TV has this problem after deleting or inserting a row/ data.

Comment: Ok thanks. But the exception break point did the same thing :)

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer.

Comment: PS: If you are deleting some rows, be sure that you're deleting the row before deleting the data from your array.